# Search all the pdf irrespective of their case using redirect rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a pdf files in sites/default/files but when i hit url ie http://example.com/sites/default/files/Xyz.pdf it should search for http://example.com/sites/default/files/xyz.pdf instead of providing result of  page not found.

**Update :**
file names can be camel case also . I dont want to use mod_speiling are there any other options??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess or other URL Case Sensitive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270772/htaccess-or-other-url-case-sensitive)

Comment: Why do you have mixed case filenames in UR? Better you fix wrong URLs on your site

Comment: We have migrated the files so we have files in camel case and we cant edit file names now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the response from this [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2270864/5659190):

Case sensitivity depends on the file system, not Apache.  There is a partial solution, however.  mod_rewrite can coerce everything to lowercase (or uppercase) like so:

```
RewriteMap tolowercase int:tolower 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${tolowercase:$1}
```

Reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap

Unfortunately, this only works if all your files are lowercase, while you specifies mixed case filenames (Fruit.php.)  Are you comfortable renaming all the files in your project lowercase?