# Codeigniter 3 Uploading to Linux Hosting

Tags: php, linux, apache, codeigniter

so I know that in CI 3, I need to change the naming conventions such as having controllers first letter into uppercase. When I upload to a Linux web hosting, I want to have a Windows-like URL convention.
For example, in Windows, i can access a website like: http://www.example.com/controller ; while in Linux, doing so will result into an error because it should have been: http://www.example.com/Controller .

My question is that is it possible to override this restriction on having controllers have their first letter as uppercase? Can it be done with .htaccess?

I wanted to implement this since I want to have the freedom of specifically accessing controller vs Controller everytime I want to manually enter the website URL.

Answer (score 0):

For linux try mod_speling for apache and use the `CheckCaseOnly On` directive.

In your `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file...

```
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
  CheckSpelling On
  CheckCaseOnly On
</IfModule>
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_speling.html

Comment: Where do I modify this in the CPanel?

Comment: Sorry, you can add the above to .htaccess. (I put it in httpd.conf because I have control of the server.)

Comment: So there isn't any other workaround except to rename all the redirects to uppercase? :(

Comment: It does have to be enabled in httpd.conf by the host provider though.

Comment: I have this in my .htaccess but it still won't work. 

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_speling.c>
  CheckSpelling On
  CheckCaseOnly On
</IfModule>`

Comment: Mod_speling might not be enabled on your host server. [The same question was answered here too.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270772/htaccess-or-other-url-case-sensitive). Maybe that page has more insights?